# Arduino Parse Cloud Code

Tags: parse-platform, cloud, arduino-yun

I am trying to pass a variable (emailAddress) to Parse Cloud Code from Arduino.

```
ParseCloudFunction cloudFunction;
cloudFunction.setFunctionName("SendEmail");
cloudFunction.add("email", emailAddress);
ParseResponse response2 = cloudFunction.send();
```

However, Parse sees this as a Boolean...

```
E2015-08-19T16:17:14.622Z]v10 Ran cloud function SendEmail for user XXXXXXXX with: 
Input: {"email":true} 
Result: Uh oh, something went wrong
```

Anyone know how to pass the variable without sending as a Boolean?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and i think i've just solved it.

If you change the datatype for the email address to char* (i'm assuming you were using a string before) then it should work.

I'm not 100% sure why but i think its to do with referencing a pointer. I think parse.com requires a pointer to reference a variable and so a 'String' does not have that and parse.com only sees a boolean. Anyway this may not be quite correct but all i know is when i changed my String to char* it worked!

I took the inspiration from this documentation from Parse http://parse.com/docs/arduino/api/class_parse_object_create.html

Hope it works!